# Are people less bothered by problems they create for themselves?

Tags: perception, reference-request, emotion

I notice that I am more annoyed by problems when I am not the one that created them.  Two examples would be

1. Cleaning up someone else's mess is much more annoying than cleaning up my own
2. When spelling autocorrect "fixes" a word that I typed in correctly fixing it annoys me much more than fixing words that I misspelled.

My second example alludes to the fact that this is a very important phenomenon to consider when automating a process.  A user could be much more annoyed by fixing a mistake caused by the automation than they would have been doing the whole thing themselves.

I have been unable to find a name for this phenomenon or any research relating to it.  Is it true in general? Is there a name for it that would point me towards some research?

Comment: It could be related to a person's sense of independence

Comment: Just a thought: Humans are engineered to put themselves first in any situation. It is a lot easier to be angered at a mistake caused by something/someone else since you dont see the viewpoint of the person creating it.